# How go get address of slice as u64?

Tags: c, rust

I transfered this C struct:

```
  85 struct spi_ioc_transfer {
   86     __u64       tx_buf;
   87     __u64       rx_buf;
   88 
   89     __u32       len;
   90     __u32       speed_hz;
   91 
   92     __u16       delay_usecs;
   93     __u8        bits_per_word;
   94     __u8        cs_change;
   95     __u32       pad;
   96 
   97     /* If the contents of 'struct spi_ioc_transfer' ever change
   98      * incompatibly, then the ioctl number (currently 0) must change;
   99      * ioctls with constant size fields get a bit more in the way of
  100      * error checking than ones (like this) where that field varies.
  101      *
  102      * NOTE: struct layout is the same in 64bit and 32bit userspace.
  103      */
  104 };
```

to Rust:

```
struct SpiIocTransfer {
    tx_buf: u64,
    rx_buf: u64,
    len: u32,
    speed_hz: u32,
    delay_usecs: u16,
    bits_per_word: u8,
    cs_change: u8,
    pad: u32
    /* If the contents of 'struct spi_ioc_transfer' ever change
    * incompatibly, then the ioctl number (currently 0) must change;
    * ioctls with constant size fields get a bit more in the way of
    * error checking than ones (like this) where that field varies.
    *
    * NOTE: struct layout is the same in 64bit and 32bit userspace.
    */
}
```

However, I'm having problems in filling `tx_buf` and `rx_buf`:

C version:

```
int wiringPiSPIDataRW (int channel, unsigned char *data, int len)
{
  struct spi_ioc_transfer spi ;

  channel &= 1 ;
  memset (&spi, 0, sizeof (spi)) ;

  spi.tx_buf        = (unsigned long)data ;
  spi.rx_buf        = (unsigned long)data ;
  spi.len           = len ;
```

My Rust version:

```
    pub fn spi_data_rw(&mut self, channel_: i32, data: &[u8], len: u32) -> i32 {
        let channel = channel_ & 1;
        let spi = SpiIocTransfer::new();
        spi.tx_buf        = data.as_mut_ptr();//(unsigned long) ?
        spi.rx_buf        = data.as_mut_ptr();//(unsigned long) ?
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/w25q.rs:68:29
   |
68 |         spi.rx_buf        = data.as_mut_ptr();//(unsigned long) ?
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u64`, found *-ptr
   |
   = note:     expected type `u64`
           found raw pointer `*mut u8`
```

How do I get the address of the `data` slice as an `u64`?

Comment: You can just cast it: `data.as_mut_ptr() as usize`, but also you shouldn't be directly translating C to Rust in the first place.

Comment: Since a slice already has a length, so `data: &[u8], len: u32` ends up duplicating the `len` value in 2 places, FYI.

Comment: `data.as_mut_ptr() as u64` will perform the obvious cast. But are `tx_buf` and `rx_buf` supposed to point to the same data? If not, is their length expected to be the same?

Comment: this C code look bad BTW it's clearly not standard

Comment: @Stargateur Yep, all I mean is `fn spi_data_rw(&mut self, channel_: i32, data: &[u8], len: u32) -> i32 {` is a weird signature since `len` is already available via `data.len()`, so passing it separately in params is weird.